# Eloquent Javascript Ch. 7 - assignment statement with boolean expression

Tags: javascript

I'm having difficulty understanding the "atDest" variable declaration in this lesson that appears to be taking on two values (both a boolean and an object).

http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html

```
actionTypes.eat = function(critter, vector, action) {
 var dest = this.checkDestination(action, vector);
 var atDest = dest != null && this.grid.get(dest);
 if (!atDest || atDest.energy == null)
  return false;
 critter.energy += atDest.energy;
 this.grid.set(dest, null);
 return true;
};
```

Any tips here would help. When I try testing out variables with similar syntax with console.log I've been noticing that the object value overrides the bool. Is this an inherent Javascript trait where a variable can have more than one value?

Answer (score 1):

The boolean operators `||` and `&&` actually return the value of [one of the specified operands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

```
var a = 5 || false; // 5 is assigned to a
var b = true && 5; // 5 is assigned to b
```

The logical && returns the first expression if it can be converted to false, otherwise it returns the second expression (or 5 in the example above)

So if `dest != null` is not false in the following statement

```
var atDest = dest != null && this.grid.get(dest);
```

then `atDest` is assigned the value of `this.grid.get(dest)`.

Comment: This is exactly what was hanging me up. Got caught assuming && would have to return a bool. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation you are looking for.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

The gist is that in JavaScript everything can be interpreted as boolean. The above doc makes it very clear. Values like `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, `""` will be interpreted as falsy. What `!atDest` really means is basically to check if `atDest` is not assigned (likely `null` or `undefined`).

The next part is also worthy mentioning. `atDest.energy == null` is a loose equality check (notice the `==` instead of `===`). This check will actually check for both `null` and `undefined`. But the difference between `atDest.energy == null` and `!atDest.energy` is that `atDest.energy == null` will not match `0`, `""`, nor `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript values can be falsy like

> ```
> false
> 0 (zero)
> "" (empty string)
> null
> undefined
> NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)
> ```

or truthy, which is everything else **including the empty object {}**. Falsy values are equivalent to false in a boolean check and truthy values are equivalent to true in a boolean check.

---

Now, if you attempt to read a non-existent property on an object you'll get `undefined`. However if you attempt to read a non defined property off the special value of `null` or `undefined`, you will get an error. Something like

> Unable to get property 'energy' of undefined or null reference

if you *attempt* to read atDest.energy when atDest is null or undefined.

---

So if you want to check if a property is of value xyz on an object that you are not sure is null or undefined, you have to do 2 things

1. First check if you can actually read the property without error i.e. that the **object** is not null or undefined.
2. Then read the property and do the check.

---

In your example, this

```
if (!atDest || atDest.energy == null)
```

does pretty something equivalent. This part

```
!atDest
```

evaluates to false if atDest is null or undefined (because both these values are falsy) and **short circuits** the loop (i.e. **doesn't read** atDest.energy). In effect what the code *attempts* to do is this

```
if (atDest === undefined || atDest === null) {
      .... do something ....
else if (atDest.energy == null) {
      .... do same something ....
else
      .... do something different ....
```